# ISPConfig change default version PHP

Tags: php, linux, debian, ispconfig

I have a server with ISPConfig with the version of PHP 5.6 by default. I installed in addition PHP 7 and defined my site with PHP 7 except that when I do a composer update or install I need the version of PHP 7. Is there a way to say to compose Based on the php version of the site? Or otherwise how to change the default PHP version of ISPConfig? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after following this tutorial: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/
I have to use composer this way according to the location of my other php version.

/opt/php-7.1/bin/php  /usr/local/bin/composer install

composer use the correct php version.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build it yourself as far as I'm concerned. You can follow this guide to do so:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/

Comment: I followed this tuto the problem is that when I do a php -v I'm still in 5.6.

Thank you